# Aplicação PhoneGap de 3MB aumenta para quase 220MB. Poderiam me explicar?

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou desenvolvendo minha primeira aplicação PhoneGap para Android e me deparo com algo que me assustou bastante. A aplicação, que até o momento só tem interface, nada de regra de negócio aumentou seu tamanho drasticamente. Inicialmente ela não passava de 3mb, porém, só fiz o favor de subir a aplicação para o Bitbucket da empresa (git) e quando fui emular a mesma a seguir se tornou um absurdo. de 3mb foi para 220mb. Saberiam o que pode ser, lembrando que a aplicação não tem nenhuma regra de negócio operando, somente 4 telas criadas com html5, js e css.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Será que você esta fazendo o clone da pasta toda direto do bitbucket?

Se isso acontecer ele pega TODA a referencia do git, essa provavelmente é a causa...

Tente esse comando para pegar só os arquivos:

```
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master
```

ai depois vc unzip e ve quantos megas deram... 
Acredito que seja só isso mesmo.

Comment: Realmente, o problema é na pasta git. Como eu fiz o primeiro commit da aplicação, ele criou o diretório .git e incluiu no projeto. Essa foi a causa, agora estou ignorando a pasta .git na criação do apk e o problema foi resolvido. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Para quem tiver o mesmo problema, basta clicar com o botão direito em cima do projeto > Properties > Resource > Resource Filters > Add ... Adiciona a pasta .git e seleciona Folders, com isso o problema está resolvido.